# Best tools to create valid XML files from an Excel file

Tags: c#, python, xml, excel, vb6

I need to create a script that extracts some data from a complex Excel 2003 file (with multiple sheets and different tables inside a single sheet) and produces different XML files that need to be validated against a given XSD file.

My preferred language is Python;
to create and validate XML files i would go with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/).
What do you suggest for parsing XLS files?
Is [xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm) the right tool to use for complex Excel files?
Or do i need to convert all the sheets in CSV manually, and read files line by line, splitting and getting data?

I accept C#, VB6, VBA suggestions too.

Comment: Is it .xslx Office 2007 format by any chance?

Comment: Will the script or process have access to Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[disclaimer: I'm the author of xlrd]

xlrd is quite suited for this kind of job. Get the latest version from [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). Get the flavour from the tutorial found [here](http://www.python-excel.org). XLSX support is in alpha test; e-mail me if you need it. The awkwardness and lossiness of the save-as-CSV approach was one of the things that prompted me to write xlrd.

Answer (score 2):

Xlrd is OK. We use it extensively to import XLS files full of references and formulas with multiple sheets and data presented in custom (not Latin-1) encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I am convinced the most simple solution for this task is using Excel VBA together with MSXML parser. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba) for some links how to use the MSXML parser in VBA for reading XML files; you can adopt this easily for writing XML files, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer whether xlrd/python is the right tool for the job - as I don't know python well enough.

But there are many ways to access the excel data...in the main you have VBA built directly in to Excel.

Then you have Ado.net [See David Hayden's article here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) which allows you to access the data via any DotNet language...even [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)

Comment: Sheets have more than one tables (headers on different rows), does ADO work also in this case?

Comment: I tried ADO.net and it fails for complex sheets. Sees them as seperate sheets. xlrd saw them correctly, but then you have to import python :-)