# Getting info out of XML document in VBA

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, msxml

I'm using MSXML2 to load an XML file (a feed from Google Analytics).

I now need to get data out of it, but I can't figure out how.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:dxp='http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='W/"dsdsdsdsdsdsdsd."' gd:kind='analytics#data'>
  <id>http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:2000000&amp;dimensions=ga:campaign&amp;metrics=ga:visits&amp;filters=ga:campaign%3D%3Dcrosspromo&amp;start-date=2010-08-26&amp;end-date=2010-09-09</id>
  <updated>2010-09-09T05:50:40.705-07:00</updated>
  <title>Google Analytics Data for Profile 2000000</title>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?max-results=50&amp;end-date=2010-09-09&amp;start-date=2010-08-26&amp;metrics=ga%3Avisits&amp;ids=ga%3A2000000&amp;dimensions=ga%3Acampaign&amp;filters=ga%3Acampaign%3D%3Dcrosspromo' />
  <author>
    <name>Google Analytics</name>
  </author>
  <generator version='1.0'>Google Analytics</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>1&lt;
  /openSearch:totalResults&gt;
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>50</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <dxp:aggregates>
    <dxp:metric confidenceInterval='0.0' name='ga:visits' type='integer' value='5070' />
  </dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:dataSource>
    <dxp:property name='ga:profileId' value='2000000' />
    <dxp:property name='ga:webPropertyId' value='UA-2000000-1' />
    <dxp:property name='ga:accountName' value='test' />
    <dxp:tableId>ga:2000000</dxp:tableId>
    <dxp:tableName>test</dxp:tableName>
  </dxp:dataSource>
  <dxp:endDate>2010-09-09</dxp:endDate>
  <dxp:startDate>2010-08-26</dxp:startDate>
  <entry gd:etag='W/"CkMEQX47eSp7I2A9Wx5QGUQ."' gd:kind='analytics#datarow'>
    <id>http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:2000000&amp;ga:campaign=crosspromo&amp;filters=ga:campaign%3D%3Dcrosspromo&amp;start-date=2010-08-26&amp;end-date=2010-09-09</id>
    <updated>2010-09-08T17:00:00.001-07:00</updated>
    <title>ga:campaign=crosspromo</title>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.google.com/analytics' />
    <dxp:dimension name='ga:campaign' value='crosspromo' />
    <dxp:metric confidenceInterval='0.0' name='ga:visits' type='integer' value='5070' />
  </entry></openSearch:totalResults>
</feed>
```

Then I load the XML and search for the "entry" tag:

```
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
objXML.loadXML strXML
Debug.Print objXML.getElementsByTagName("entry").Item(0).Text
```

But this outputs:

```
http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:20000000&ga:campaign=crosspromo&filters=ga:campaign%3D%3Dcrosspromo&start-date=2010-08-26&end-date=2010-09-092010-09-08T17:00:00.001-07:00ga:campaign=crosspromo
```

Where's the rest of the data?
If I try item(1) it fails...

Answer (score 4):

Well Item(1) fails because there is only one "entry" element, and that's at 0.

The .Text property returns all the Text content of the element **and all its children**. If you look closely, that's what you've got.

If you want something else, you'll have to use the appropriate method off the Item(0).

Check out this question ([How to parse XML in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba)).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LoadXmlDoc() As DOMDocument
    Dim aDoc As DOMDocument
    Set aDoc = New DOMDocument
    aDoc.async = False
    aDoc.Load ("feedfile.xml")
    Set LoadXmlDoc = aDoc
End Function

'' Direct access
Public Sub getEntry()
    Dim aDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim aNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Set aDoc = LoadXmlDoc
    Set aNode = aDoc.SelectSingleNode("//entry")
    Debug.Print aNode.XML
End Sub

'' search for it
Public Sub findEntry()
    Dim aDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim aNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim aNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set aDoc = LoadXmlDoc
    Set aNodes = aDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    For Each aNode In aNodes
        Debug.Print aNode.XML
    Next
End Sub

'' get the entry date
Public Sub getDate()
    Dim aDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim aNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Set aDoc = LoadXmlDoc
    Set aNode = aDoc.SelectSingleNode("//entry/updated")
    Debug.Print aNode.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received all the information you asked for. You got the text of each element within the `<entry></entry>`

lets break it down (this was your output):

First set of text:

```
http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:20000000&ga:campaign=crosspromo&filters=ga:campaign%3D%3Dcrosspromo&start-date=2010-08-26&end-date=2010-09-09
```

Second Set of text:

```
2010-09-08T17:00:00.001-07:00
```

Third set of text:

```
ga:campaign=crosspromo
```

There was nothing else in the entry with output. Therefore you do not see anything else.