# Parsing XML in VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I have an XML `ResponseXML` object. I'd like to loop throught all nodes called "XYZ". How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse XML in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some functions you can use for **parsing** your **XML**:

```
Private xml As MSXML.DOMDocument

Private Sub loadXMLFile(xmlFile)    
    Set xml = New DOMDocument
    xml.async = False
    xml.Load (xmlFile) 
End Sub

Private Sub loadXMLString(xmlString)    
    Set xml = New DOMDocument
    xml.LoadXml (xmlString) 
End Sub

Public Function getNodeValue(xpath As String) As String    
    getNodeValue = xml.SelectSingleNode(strXPath).Text    
End Function

Public Function getNodes(xpath as string) As IXMLDOMNodeList            
    Set getNodes = xml.SelectNodes(xpath)
End Function

Public Function getNode(xpath as string) As IXMLDOMNode
    Set getNode = xml.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
End Function
```

See MSDN for more information about MSXML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx

Comment: Worth remembering that `DOMDocument` is a synonym for `DOMDocument30` (i.e. MXSML v3.0) and that any more recent version has to have the full version specified as in `DOMDocument60` (for MSXML v6.0) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757837%28VS.85%29.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may find useful to be able to parse an XML object in VBA.

See this question: [How to parse XML using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba)

HTH!

Specifically [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba/11406#11406) covers your problem