# Parsing excel data ( containing xml ) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have a simple excel file containing rows and columns. One of the column contains rows of data which is string like this (XML data)

```
<Employee Name="R1" Designation="Developer">
   <SkillSet Language="C#"/>
</Employee>
<Employee Name="E2" Designation="Developer">
   <SkillSet Language="Java"/>
</Employee>
```

I would like to read this information in the excel file, parse it based on particular skillset and put them in the same excel workbook in adjacent column. I may need to provide a button click which may trigger the action.

How do I approach this problem.

Should I write a macro or should I write an excel addin. The excel can be either 2003 or earlier/2007/2010.

I can think of writing a user defined function to read the cell data but, how do I read through the columns in vb and also how do I re-use my function across different excel-workbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this maybe coming to you at a late hour, however I had thesame problem as you mention. I'm also kind of new to VBA. My client wanted a database application in Access 2003. But after some persuation, I was able to convince them to adapt Access 2007. Which by the way, it's still not reliable, to develop a multi-lingual application.

Anyway to cut the story short, I was able to achieve same, after some google search and using the code I found here;

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2922

and here

[Parsing XML in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550212/parsing-xml-in-vba)

Hope you find this links helpful cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference (Tools-->References) to an XML parser, e.g., Microsoft XML, v6.0  -- my MS Access 2010 installation has a seven XML parsers provided by Microsoft.  Declare an instance of the parser and use its properties and methods as you need.

Comment: thanks, I shall try that out as an option. But the good thing is the client is ready to use Excel 2007 and above.. So I started creating  excel addins using VSTO.. I now read XElement.Parse and get my thing done quite easily..  I sure will try this out. but until then I cannot vote this as answer.. But sure will upvote !