# Excel VBA Split() with a whole word as delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, split

I want to split an XML Code after an command i.e. ....`<car>BMW3</car>`
There is a lot of stuff in front of this command so I would like to use the Splitfunction with "`<car>`" as delimiter. 
Is there a way to make this possible or is there another function or VBA code to make this happen?

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: You should really use an XML Parser to parse XML, not string functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550212/parsing-xml-in-vba | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba

Comment: Agree with Alex, but this works `?split( "somestuff<car>morestuff","<car>")( 1)` so what's the question?

Comment: Thanks... I was reading the documentation of "split" and always read, that there is only one character possible. But you're right. Works just fine. Will look into xml parser!

Answer (score 0):

That should do it : Replace `String` with your whole text, and `WordDeliminter` with your delimiter.

```
SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(String,WordDeliminter,";"),";")
```