# How to parse XML in VBA Excel 2003?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am trying to parse a general XML file, via VBA.  What I want to do with it: extract the values of the xml nodes, write them into a XML file and export it.

Do you know any library that actually lets me read one node at a time, for me to process with a understandable documentation, and some examples, even minimal ones.

So far:

```
Sub Go()

    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xmlElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.Load ("E:\cdCatalog.xml")

    Set xmlElement = xmlDoc.documentElement
    Set xmlNode = xmlElement.FirstChild

    parseNodes xmlElement, 1, 1
    'parseNodes xmlNode, 1, 1

End Sub

Sub parseNodes(node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement, i As Integer, j As Integer)
    Dim child As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    'result = node.baseName & " : " & node.Text
    result = node.nodeName

    Sheet1.Activate
    ' text if...
    Cells(i, j) = result

    j = j + 1
    If (node.hasChildNodes) Then

        For Each child In node.childNodes
            i = i + 1
            'MsgBox child.Text
            MsgBox TypeName(node.childNodes)
            parseNodes child, i, j
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you correct it. Else type "VBA DOM XML tutorial" in your favourite search engine.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am now struggling to understand why 
" Dim gReader As New XmlTextReader(FileName) " is an error. Thanks.

Comment: I see you've changed your question pretty extensively. You should really accept an answer and start a new question if you want to get help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing your updated question as specified in your comment:

You can't instance objects in VBA like that, with an argument in the `Dim` statement. Try:

```
Dim gReader As XmlTextReader
gReader = New XmlTextReader
```

Also, I suggest you read the `XmlTextReader` documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1af7xa52.aspx

The examples illustrate how to use `XmlTextReader`.

**EDIT:** As far as I can tell from a cursory internet search, `XmlTextReader` is implemented for .NET but not for VBA.

You may want to consider using DOM instead of `XmlTextReader`. I find DOM relatively easy to use. The downside is that it is inefficient for very large XML files. Unless you are manipulating large files, DOM should work fine for you.

```
Dim xlmDoc As Object
Set xlmDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Load fileName
```

Comment: So.. first of all.. Thank you for your help. But I couldn't use XmlTextReader. Maybe I am a too noob, but it doesn't work (for me). I've updated my code so far.. Now i have a reference mismatch :(