# domdocument issue in visual basic

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, vba, domdocument, ixmldomdocument

I am thinking of working on an XML file in Visual Basic. When I tried it using `DOMDOCUMENT`, Visual Basic is showing an error. It is not recognizing what `DOCUMENT` is. Do I have to call a library to make it work? Take a look at my code:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Function getDistance(Origin As String, Destination As String) As Double
    Dim HttpReq As Object
    Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim distanceNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    HttpReq.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & Origin & "&destinations=" & Destination & "&sensor=false", False
    HttpReq.send
    MsgBox HttpReq.responseText
    Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
    myDomDoc.LoadXML HttpReq.responseText
    Set distanceNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/value")
    getDistance = distanceNode.Text / 1000
End Function
```

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-in-vba

Comment: BTW what has this to do with Visual Studio?

Comment: You have to reference to 'Microsoft XML, v6.0' library in order to use the DomDocument.

Comment: Use myDomDoc.LoadXML if loading from a string. If you have the xml file address, then use myDomDoc.Load.

Answer (score -1):

Project References:

```
System.XML
```

Add `Imports System.Xml` to your imports list

Create a Variable similar to:

```
Dim MyXMLDoc As New XmlDocument
```

To load a document use:

```
 MyXMLDoc.Load("Document path here")
```

To read nodes something similar to this should work:

```
Dim Items as Xml.XmlNodeList = MyXMLDoc.SelectNodes("ParentNode/ChildNodes")
Dim Item as Xml.XmlNode
Try
  For Each Item in Items
    Dim randomstring As String = Item.GetAttributes.GetNamedItem("ItemName").value
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

etc...

Hope this is mildly useful

Comment: `Hope this is mildly useful` - it isn't, because it's VB.NET and the question is about VBA.