# Vba-Excel How to generate XML file from a SpreadSheet of Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for the logic to convert the SpreadSheet data of an excel into XML format.
[image]

I have the thousands of data like shown below. i want to convert this into XML format.
Anyone please help me, any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, your Excel version allows to save your document using `XML Spreadsheet 2003` format: `Save As... > Other Formats` and locate it in the dropdown (at least for Excel 2007 it works as described).

Resulting XML will contain much of the native Excel Workbook fields and nodes, but they're might be easily removed using any more or less advanced XML editor, e.g. **Altova XMLSpy** or any similar. However, cleanup depends entirely on your further needs.

For your convenience may see sample Excel book and XML generated from it as described above: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxmxu2tq52y4m9b/ExcelToXML.zip

Good luck!

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala These links may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11305/1953175 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163921%28v=office.10%29.aspx Good luck!