# Reading XML Websites in VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I have a webpage which is in xml and I'd like to read this information into an excel macro that I am making.  However, I'm not quite sure how to go about it in visual basic.  I've been coming at it like this...

```
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=requestURL, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
```

Which is OK in a sense that I get the data into a workbook that I can then manipulate.  However, I'd much prefer for the data not to be put into a workbook, i.e read it in directly.
I've seen some people approach this by reading the webpage and storing it as a string first, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct approach built-in to VBA?  Thanks.

Comment: See this [Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11305/1490783).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what approach you've seen, but the most direct way to handle this in VBA is to send a GET request via the MSMXL2.XMLHTTP object and get back the XML file.  Then create an MSXML2.DOMDocument and fill it from the ResponseXML property of the XMLHTTP.