# Activating closed workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I am using the function below to extract data from other workbooks.

```
Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    'Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim myArg As String
    
    'Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Create the argument
    myArg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    
    'Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(myArg)

End Function
```

I am calling this function like this:

```
Sub TestGetValue()
    Dim p As String, f As String
    Dim s As String, a As String
    p = "C:\Users\schaudha\Desktop\FIT transition\test simulation results"
    f = "all cancer rate.xml"
    s = "CONTENTS"
    a = "A1"
    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)
End Sub
```

This function seems to work only when the workbook is active. I mean, if I open the Excel file that I need data from and then run my subroutine, it works, but if it is closed, it doesn't work. I would also like it work when the workbook is closed. I am guessing I need to activate the workbook somehow before I use `ExecuteExcel4Macro(myArg)`. How do I do that? I plan on using this function to extract data from thousands to cells from about a hundred workbooks, so I want to make this code as efficient as possible.

Comment: Set oSpreadsheet = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & file)

Comment: Your workbook is not an Excel workbook, it's an XML file, which is why the code doesn't work. You would have to actually open the file as a workbook, or use a different method to parse the XML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

'Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
Dim myArg As String

Dim CurrBook As Workbook

'Make sure the file exists
If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"

If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If

Application.Workbooks.Open (path & file)

'Create the argument
myArg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

'Execute an XLM macro
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(myArg)

Application.Workbooks(file).Close (False)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is (modified from your code):

```
If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
else
    CurrBook = Workbooks.Open Path & File
End If
'''Code here
CurrBook.Close
```

This will open the file, if it's found, and you'll be able to extract the data from it. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to open the workbook you don't need `ExecuteExcel4Macro` at all:

```
Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    Dim CurrBook As Workbook
    
    'Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set CurrBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & file)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    GetValue = CurrBook.Sheets(sheet).Range(ref).Value
    
    CurrBook.Close savechanges:=False

End Function
```

Comment: yeah I figured, can you think of a way to extract data from xml files without really opening them?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "opening" I think. ;) There are a few examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba