# VBA Split HTML String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a field in a SQL-Server 2008R2 table which contains values like this (all lines in one field):

```
<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Name Ltd.</font></div>

<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Adress</font></div>

<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Zip-code MyCustomer City</font></div>
```

I am working in Access 2010 and have to Export this Content into an Excel sheet with 3 columns: Name, Adress, Zip+City

I tried with

```
Split(rs("Myfield"), "<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>")
```

but it does not work.

Any idea how to split this string?
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting it on the wrong delimiter...

**Logic**

1. Replace `<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>` in the main string with blank
2. Split on `</font></div>`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String

    's = rs("Myfield")
    s = "<div><font face=""""Times New Roman"""" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Name Ltd.</font></div>" & _
        "<div><font face=""""Times New Roman"""" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Adress</font></div>" & _
        "<div><font face=""""Times New Roman"""" size=3 color=black>MyCustomer Zip-code MyCustomer City</font></div>"

    'Debug.Print s

    s = Replace(s, "<div><font face=""""Times New Roman"""" size=3 color=black>", "")

    Debug.Print Split(s, "</font></div>")(0) '<~~ MyCustomer Name Ltd.
    Debug.Print Split(s, "</font></div>")(1) '<~~ MyCustomer Adress
    Debug.Print Split(s, "</font></div>")(2) '<~~ MyCustomer Zip-code MyCustomer City
End Sub
```

Comment: A good solution as long as the font values stay the same. If that's not the case (or you want to look into XML handling anyway) have a look at [this overview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11325/4600127) on XML handling by rjzii in VBA.

Comment: True. I gave a solution based on user data. If you see the question, OP is trying to split on the font values so I can safely assume that they are same ;)

Comment: I didn't want to criticise your answer, it's great and more importantly simple. I just wanted to provide an outlook for when matters become more complicated :-)

Comment: Don't worry. I took it positively ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Yes, fortunately the font values are always the same.
Pls help me with a further Problem I discovered: the number of lines differ! That makes it neccessary to Loop, but I can't find how.
     s() = rs("MyField")
    s() = Replace(s(), "<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>", "")
    
    For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s) 
    Debug.Print Split(s, "</font></div>")(i)
    next i

Fails with an Error at Replace (s().... Argument byRef not matching

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your question with your new query? It is difficult reading it in comments @user3480989

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Siddharth my incorrect use of comments.

Meanwhile I managed my Problem of variable number of lines by this

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
m = rs("MyField")
m = Replace(m, "<div><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=3 color=black>", "")
s() = Split(m, "</font></div>")

For i = LBound(s()) To UBound(s()) 
    Debug.Print s(i)

Next i

rs.MoveNext
```

Loop

Thanks again yr. reply!
Michael