# VBA and SOAP interface

Tags: xml, vba, soap

I am trying to connect one MS Access database to a SOAP service.

I was able to connect to the service, retrieve the XML, but I can't read a node value.

This is my code (I replaced some confidential things with `++++++`):

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub lanzar_XML_Click()
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhtp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim limpiartexto As String
    Dim Valoresxml  As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    sUrl = "++++++"
    sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:hai=""++++++"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <soapenv:Header/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   <soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <hai:QuerySRInfo>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <SRNum>EUES160624000378</SRNum>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <ServiceCenterId>++++++</ServiceCenterId>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "         <ServiceCenterPW>++++++</ServiceCenterPW>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      </hai:QuerySRInfo>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "   </soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
    Set xmlhtp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With xmlhtp
        .Open "POST", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
        ' .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction:", "rpc/http://www.++++++.com/:QuerySRInfo"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "Lenght"
        .send sEnv

        Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        xmlDoc.loadXML .responseText

        limpiartexto = xmlDoc.XML
        limpiartexto = Right(limpiartexto, Len(limpiartexto) - 327)
        limpiartexto = Left(limpiartexto, Len(limpiartexto) - 64)

        Debug.Print limpiartexto
    End With

    xmlDoc.loadXML limpiartexto

    For Each Valoresxml In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ServiceRequests")
        Me.MobilePhone = Valoresxml.selectNodes("MobilePhone")(0).Text
        MsgBox Valoresxml.selectNodes("MobilePhone")(0).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

I believe my problem is with the format of the XML that is retrieved, instead of a well structured XML, it is just a one-liner containing all nodes.

My `debug.print` returns:

```
<ServiceRequests><ServiceRequest xmlns="http://www.siebel.com/xml/SPI%20HET%20ASC%20Query%20Service%20Request"><SrNumber>EUES160624000378</SrNumber><CustomerName>++++++</CustomerName><FirstName>++++++</FirstName><LastName>++++++</LastName><ContactEmail></ContactEmail><MobilePhone>600600600</MobilePhone><HomePhone></HomePhone><WorkPhone></WorkPhone><CustomerGender></CustomerGender><CustomerCoutnry>Spain</CustomerCoutnry><CustomerState></CustomerState><SubmissionTime></SubmissionTime><OfflineSubmissionTime></OfflineSubmissionTime></ServiceRequest></ServiceRequests>
```

...but I think it should return:

```
<ServiceRequests>
 <ServiceRequest xmlns="http://www.siebel.com/xml/SPI%20HET%20ASC%20Query%20Service%20Request">    
  <SrNumber>EUES160624000378</SrNumber>
  <CustomerName>++++++</CustomerName>
  <FirstName>++++++</FirstName>
  <LastName>++++++</LastName>
  <ContactEmail></ContactEmail>
  <MobilePhone>600600600</MobilePhone>
  <HomePhone></HomePhone>
  <WorkPhone></WorkPhone>
  <CustomerGender></CustomerGender>
  <CustomerCoutnry>Spain</CustomerCoutnry>
  <CustomerState></CustomerState>
  <SubmissionTime></SubmissionTime>
  <OfflineSubmissionTime></OfflineSubmissionTime>
 </ServiceRequest>
</ServiceRequests>
```

How can I deal with that?

Note: when I use `soapui`, the returned XML looks fine.

Comment: XML/MSXML doesn't care about line breaks. Is that what the problem is? How is it a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate, as you should not "parse" XML with string functions like `Left` and `Right`. Instead use an DOM API for that. That way that kind of spacing (or lack of it) becomes irrelevant. The API takes care of all that.

Comment: @trincot the interesting part is that OP *is already using MSXML*....... and then works of the XML string.

Answer (score 0):

The response XML has an undeclared namespace that should be declared with any string prefix (below uses *doc*) to reference underlying elements. Use this prefix in any node  path references. Then, iterate using a nodeList. Of course this assumes *limpiartexto* renders a valid XML after `Left()` and `Right()` handling.

```vb
Dim XMLNamespaces As String                 ' among other references
Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
...
xmlDoc.loadXML limpiartexto
XMLNamespaces = "xmlns:doc='http://www.siebel.com/xml/SPI%20HET%20ASC%20Query%20Service%20Request'"
XmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XMLNamespaces

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//doc:ServiceRequest")

For Each Valoresxml In xmlNodeList
    Me.MobilePhone = Valoresxml.SelectSingleNode("doc:MobilePhone").Text
    MsgBox Valoresxml.SelectSingleNode("doc:MobilePhone").Text
Next Valoresxml
```