# Parse line from HTML response in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xml-parsing, winhttprequest

I am looking to parse a 'WinHttpRequest' response in Excel VBA to pull a specific line from the HTML response. Here is the code for the HTTP request.

```
Function getSetName(ByVal setNUMBER As String) As String
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Dim xmlResponse As String
    Dim setDescription As String
    Dim setName As String
   

    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    oRequest.Open "GET", "https://brickset.com/sets/75192" '& setNUMBER
    oRequest.Send
    xmlResponse = oRequest.ResponseText
    
    'parse xml response here
    
    getSetName = setName

End Function
```

I am looking to parse only the line with the HTML tag 'meta name=""description""' to a string which I will later pull information from.

Any help or direction on how to parse this single line would be appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on SO (and elsewhere) covering parsing XM. 
 E.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba?rq=1  Are you really parsing XML though, or HTML?

Comment: You are correct, am parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Test_GetSetName()
    Debug.Print GetSetName("75192")
End Sub

Function GetSetName(ByVal SetNUMBER As String) As String
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "https://brickset.com/sets/" & SetNUMBER, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    GetSetName = html.querySelector("[name='description']").Content
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, just needed to make sure the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" was also selected under Tool > References.