# NEW UPS rest API in VBA need XML response

Tags: xml, ups

I am changing over to the new UPS rest API that uses oAuth2.0. I used to get the response in XML not I am not. What can I change to get the response in XML format?

I changed the script to get the TRACKING response to their new posted script. I don't know if the old way using the new Bearer and Token would work. The new response looks different than before, don't know why they did that, this is a lot of work to adjust to the new output.

**Current response in XML:**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <TrackResponse><Response><TransactionReference><CustomerContext>...</CustomerContext> </TransactionReference><ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>
```

**New response style:**

```
 {"trackResponse":{"shipment":[{"inquiryNumber":"1Z...","package":[{"trackingNumber":...
```

new code ....

```
      With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://wwwcie.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/1Z.....?locale=en_US&returnSignature=false&returnMilestones=true"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + strClientToken
        .setRequestHeader "transId", "string"
        .setRequestHeader "transactionSrc", "testing"
        .send
        Debug.Print .responseText
                
        strFile_Path = "C:\test.txt"
        Open strFile_Path For Output As #1  
        Print #1, .responseText
        Close #1
End With
```

Old URL won't work in new script : "https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track"

```
current post script: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
<AccessLicenseNumber>....</AccessLicenseNumber>
 <UserId>....</UserId>
 <Password>....</Password>
 </AccessRequest>
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <TrackRequest>
 <Request>
 <TransactionReference>
 <CustomerContext>....</CustomerContext>
 </TransactionReference>
 <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
 </Request> <TrackingNumber>1Z....</TrackingNumber> </TrackRequest>
```

update, found this on their website, does this mean that the response is not in XML anymore? ...The second step in the process will be to review all the new API definitions that are present in our . Any UPS API integrations using XML, SOAP or legacy JSON payloads will be required to convert to the RESTful APIs found in the API Catalogue. This will involve reworking the construction of your API request payloads. API sample requests can be found for all APIs in the API documentation, and sample integrations for each API can be found in the UPS UPS GitHub The new API endpoints will only support a RESTful request, and many of the APIs have a slightly different request structure. The new API endpoints and payloads will need to be integrated into your software, along with the new OAuth security (bearer token) model.

Comment: See UPS guide : https://developer.ups.com/oauth-developer-guide?loc=en_US  I would not use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.  MSXML2 probably doesn't support OAUTH2.  I would get xml response and then parse the xml string after you get the response.  See following for parsing XML in VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba.  I probably wouldn't use VBA and would upgrade to a Powershell script.

Comment: Thank you jdweng. The MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP is working, just the response is not in XML. Would like to get same output we used to get from UPS.

Comment: See tag ShipmentConfirmRequest in following sample https://gist.github.com/jonnyeom/b150fe8d1ad5dfc95242418dc8a265ed

Comment: @jdweng , that sample is using the license, pw and id, which is the old way, UPS is changing the authorization to oauth2.0 .....Beginning June 3, 2024, access keys will no longer be supported for authentication to any UPS APIs...

Comment: Do not get Authentication and Credentials confused.  OAUTH2 only changes the Authentication, not the credentials.  OAUTH2 is a two step authentication.  Step 1 is to get a token/cookie from server.  Step 2 is to make a request and the request includes the token from step 1.  Credentials is a username and password.  So are you successfully completing step 1?  Step 2 the only changes is to include the cookie from step 1.  What did you change in the request from old code besides the authentication?

Comment: You are getting a response status code of 1 which means authentication is working.  The link below says "A "1" normally indicates a successful response, whereas a "0" indicates a Transient or Hard error."  See https://developer.ups.com/api/reference/quantumview/errors?loc=en_US

Answer (score 0):

No XML response possible with new API after June.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).